# How to print wchar_t string in lldb?

Tags: lldb

Given `wchar_t* str;` which points to a null-terminated utf32 (or utf16) string, what command should I use to print it in lldb?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume you want to print it as utf8.  It's a little involved - you need to create a summary provider for the type in python that returns a utf8 string for printing.  It's not especially complicated though.  Create a little python file like `~/lldb/wcharsummary.py` with contents like

```
import lldb
def wchar_SummaryProvider(valobj, dict):
  e = lldb.SBError()
  s = u'"'
  if valobj.GetValue() != 0:
    i = 0
    newchar = -1
    while newchar != 0:
      # read next wchar character out of memory
      data_val = valobj.GetPointeeData(i, 1)
      size = data_val.GetByteSize()
      if size == 1:
        newchar = data_val.GetUnsignedInt8(e, 0)    # utf-8
      if size == 2:
        newchar = data_val.GetUnsignedInt16(e, 0)   # utf-16
      if size == 4:
        newchar = data_val.GetUnsignedInt32(e, 0)   # utf-32
      else:
        return '<error>'
      if e.fail:
        return '<error>'
      i = i + 1
      # add the character to our string 's'
      if newchar != 0:
        s = s + unichr(newchar)
  s = s + u'"'
  return s.encode('utf-8')
```

Load this in to lldb and set this python function as the summary provider for wchar_t*; easiest to put this in your `~/.lldbinit` file for re-use:

```
command script import ~/lldb/wcharsummary.py
type summary add -F wcharsummary.wchar_SummaryProvider "wchar_t *"
```

then given some source that has some utf32 encoded characters in 32-bit wchar_t's,

```
NSString *str = @"こんにちは";  // 5 characters long
wchar_t *str_utf32_wchar = (wchar_t*) [[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding] bytes];
```

lldb will print them in utf8 for us:

```
Process 22278 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x1c03, 0x0000000100000e92 a.out`main + 146 at a.m:11, stop reason = step over
    #0: 0x0000000100000e92 a.out`main + 146 at a.m:11
   8    
   9        NSString *str = @"こんにちは";  // 5 characters long
   10       wchar_t *str_utf32_wchar = (wchar_t*) [[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding] bytes];
-> 11       printf ("0x%llx 0x%llx 0x%llx 0x%llx\n", (uint64_t) str_utf32_wchar[0], (uint64_t) str_utf32_wchar[1], 
   12                                                (uint64_t) str_utf32_wchar[2], (uint64_t) str_utf32_wchar[3]);
   13   
   14       [pool release];

(lldb) fr va
(NSAutoreleasePool *) pool = 0x0000000100108190
(NSString *) str = 0x0000000100001068 @"こんにちは"
(wchar_t *) str_utf32_wchar = 0x0000000100107f80 "こんにちは"

(lldb) p str_utf32_wchar
(wchar_t *) $0 = 0x0000000100107f80 "こんにちは"

(lldb) x/16b `str_utf32_wchar`
0x100107f80: 0xff 0xfe 0x00 0x00 0x53 0x30 0x00 0x00
0x100107f88: 0x93 0x30 0x00 0x00 0x6b 0x30 0x00 0x00
(lldb)
```

Comment: Is there anything specific I need to do to enable this as of Xcode 4.6.2?  I copy/pasted your sample str and str_utf32_wchar into my project and I'm still unable to see anything more than a memory address when printing the latter in lldb.  Is there any way to verify that `wcharsummary.wchar_SummaryProvider` was found?

Comment: I just tried it with Xcode 4.6.2's lldb.  When you do `type summary add -F wcharsummary.wchar_SummaryProvider "wchar_t *"` note that he `wcharsummary` part refers to the filename of the python file.  In my case, it was saved as `~/lldb/wcharsummary.py` and so the functions defined in that file are added under the `wcharsummary.` namespace in python.  If you named your python file something different, you'll need to register it differently with `type summary add`.

Comment: Hum, that is exactly how I have it set up, ala [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/be4C597C).  Still no luck. Thanks for the help, anyhow.

Comment: Are you trying to print UTF32 data?  I think the original script worked correctly for that encoding of unicode characters but I don't think it actually worked correctly for the other encodings it claims to support -- I only tested UTF32.

Comment: Yes, I tried both he example str / tr_utf32_wchar you used above and what I've really been after which is debugging std::wstring's on Mac.  Methinks the script is not being loaded when Xcode starts, is there any way to check that?

Comment: You might want to try it from the command line to simplify what's happening - load the script by hand, add the type summary by hand, examine the variable.  Note that since Xcode 4.6 branch, lldb top of tree sources have picked up built in formatters for `char16_t`, `char32_t`, and `wchar_t` - so those will probably be built in to the next Xcode release.

Comment: In wxString, the string buffer is an `int*`. Try `type summary add -F wcharsummary.wchar_SummaryProvider "int *"`. Works for wxString.

Comment: in xcode 4.5 I did type summary add -F wcharsummary.wchar_SummaryProvider "unsigned int *" and type summary add -F wcharsummary.wchar_SummaryProvider "const unsigned int *"

Comment: the `if size==2:` and `if size==4:` should be `elif size==...`

Comment: upvoting because this answer is mostly correct, except for the `elif` bug I described in me previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified Jason's code a little bit to handle `wxString` directly instead of having to change the summary for `int*` pointers.

Test it by typing the `script` command in Xcode debugger console, then pasting the code below and pressing ctrl-D. Then at the lldb prompt again, type `type summary add --python-function wxString_SummaryProvider "wxString"`. Works well with my wxWidgets build.

```
def wxString_SummaryProvider(valobj, dict):
  e = lldb.SBError()
  charPointer = valobj.GetChildMemberWithName('m_impl').GetChildMemberWithName('_M_dataplus').GetChildMemberWithName('_M_p')
  valobj = charPointer
  s = u'"'
  if valobj.GetValue() != 0:
    i = 0
    newchar = -1
    while newchar != 0:
      # read next wchar character out of memory
      data_val = valobj.GetPointeeData(i, 1)
      size = data_val.GetByteSize()
      if size == 1:
        newchar = data_val.GetUnsignedInt8(e, 0)    # utf-8
      if size == 2:
        newchar = data_val.GetUnsignedInt16(e, 0)   # utf-16
      if size == 4:
        newchar = data_val.GetUnsignedInt32(e, 0)   # utf-32
      else:
        return '<error>'
      if e.fail:
        return '<error>'
      i = i + 1
      # add the character to our string 's'
      # print "char2 = %s" % newchar
      if newchar != 0:
        s = s + unichr(newchar)
  s = s + u'"'
  return s.encode('utf-8')
```